# I have 2 NSMutableArrays that I want to store in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data, nsmutablearray

I have 2 NSMutableArrays and they will be used to fill table cells, I'm not sure if Core data can handle NSMutableArrays but is there a way to save these arrays with pre-existing data already in them? Would it also be possible to also add to these arrays later? My goal is to allow the user to add a new code and description at the same time, thus resulting in a new table cell being added. Here is how I created my two arrays could anyone show me how to put these in Core data?

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *presetList;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *codeDescArray;

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    self.presetList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"AS",
                                                       @"BCNU",
                                                       @"CL",
                                                       @"CT",
                                                       @"CUL",
                                                       @"K",
                                                       @"QSL",
                                                       @"QSL?",
                                                       @"QRX?",
                                                       @"QRV",
                                                       @"QRV?",
                                                       @"QTH",
                                                       @"QTH?",
                                                       @"R",
                                                       @"SN",
                                                       @"SOS",
                                                       @"73",
                                                       @"88",
                                                       nil];


    self.codeDescArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Wait",
                                                          @"Be seeing You",
                                                          @"Going off air",
                                                          @"Start Copying",
                                                          @"See you later",
                                                          @"Over",
                                                          @"I acknowledge receipt",
                                                          @"Do you acknowledge",
                                                          @"Should I wait",
                                                          @"Ready to copy",
                                                          @"Are you ready to copy?",
                                                          @"My location is ...",
                                                          @"What is your location?",
                                                          @"Roger",
                                                          @"Understood",
                                                          @"Distress message",
                                                          @"Best regards",
                                                          @"Love and kisses",
                                                          nil];
                       }
    return self;
}
```

I use delegation to pass data back but I want to use core data to persist the newly added strings to the "presetList" & "codeDescArray"

I also created my core data model, with my entity named "Morse" and with two attributes called "codeTitle" of type string and "codeDesc" of type string as well. These attributes are responsible for saving data to "presetList" and "codeDescArray" respectively. I just need a run down of how to store this in core data so I can work with it. Any ideas?

Morse.h -

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Morse : NSManagedObject

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *codeTitle;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *codeDesc;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store in it the array data by doing:

```
NSData *codeTitleData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.presetList];
myEntity.codeTitle = arrayData;
[self saveContext]; //Self if we are in the model class // same for other array too
```

You can retrieve the array back as

`NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:anEntity.codeTitle];` // same for other array

Comment: Ok thanks, this is great! But can I still add to these arrays later on or does archiving them make them immutable?

Comment: no, they will be mutable whenever you need to enter the data you can unarchive that as NSMutableArray and add it again archive it and save to core date.

Comment: @jumpman007 if it worked please accept and upvote the answer.